# Laravel 7: How can I restrict URL by user?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-7

I'm a newbie who is learning Laravel 7. I have developed a small web application with Laravel 7. But today I noticed one problem. That all the URLs are global, means all users can access all the URLs of my website. Suppose User A created data and it shows in a table where the edit and delete buttons exist with every row. The edit URL is like: `localhost/records/edit/5`. The problem is, that other logged-in users can access this edit page also. Like this, all the URLs are accessible by any logged-in users which is very bad.
I hope you understand what I'm saying. I have almost 250+ web routes. Is there any easy way to restrict the routes?
User can access their own data only. How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: you can use middleware : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware

Comment: I have used `'middleware' => 'auth'` this middleware.

Comment: The auth middleware only handles the authentication itself, you need to add a new middleware to check if the user has access to the page.

Comment: can you please show me how to write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to register policies and ensure users cannot access parts of the website without the correct authorization.

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#creating-policies) on how to write policies and implement them.

## Sample code:

### Policy:

```php
class RecordPolicy 
{
    public function delete(User $user, Record $record)
    {
        return $user->id === $record->user_id;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
class RecordController
{
    public function destroy(Record $record)
    {
        // Authorize the delete action before actually deleting the record
        $this->authorize('delete', $record);

        $record->delete();
    }
}
```

### Records index

```html
@foreach($records as $record)
    <div> 
        {{ $record->name }}

        {{-- Only show delete button if the authorized user can actually delete the record --}}
        @can('delete', $record)
            <form action="{{ route('records.destroy', compact('record') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit">Delete record</button>
            </form>
        @endcan
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm using the Spatie package for user roles and permission. Can I do something with that?

Comment: @ShanMdShazarulHaque171-15- As described in the [docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/blade-directives), if a user has a permission, you can simply check using the default `@can`. For roles, you can check if the user has a role, but usually it is suggested to build your application based on permissions, and assign permissions to roles.

Answer (score 0):

1. store user_id when new record added > Add `created_by` field in user_table DB
2. when user run URL > get logged-in user user_id from session and check in DB for their record > if record not found then redirect to home page with message otherwise continue.

Comment: For this, I have to add conditions for 250 routes separately and add the created_by column to the 20 tables. This is so time-consuming. Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to restrict routes to specific user.

1. Create a roles table

```
Columns (id, name) 

(1 = Super Admin, 2 = Admin, 3 = User)
```

2. Assign Roles To User While Creating new User
   i.e add role_id to users table.

```
$user = User::create([
  'name' => 'First Admin',
  'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
  'password' => Hash::make('Admin@1234'),
  'role_id'  => 2 // For admin role
]);
```

3. Then Create Middlewares for each role and restrict routes for specific users.

Admin Middleware: AdminMiddleware.php

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $allowedRoles = [2];
        if (!in_array(Auth::user()->role_id, $allowedRoles))
            {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error',__('Sorry, you are not authorized to access that location.'));
            }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

In Kernel.php

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
```

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
   // All admin Routes
});
```

**You Can also Use Spatie package for this.**

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/middleware

Just Check If Role is allowed to use that route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:admin']], function () {
    // All routes available for admin
});
```

Comment: I already created this part. But I want something else. Suppose a user created a data. And there will be edit button which holds the URl www.example.com/edit/5
Now, if another users hit this URL on browser, that user can access this URL. Which is not good,

Comment: You can store a user_id to table and store user_id of user who ever created that data. Add a check after that if(Auth::user()->id != $data->user_id) { return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Data was not created by you.'); }